# Migration doesn't have User field

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to add a User field to a model, but it's not being generated in the migration file.

```
// models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Foo(models.Model):
    """This class represents the Foo model."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                 related_name='foos',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and get this output:

```
// 0001_initial.py

migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Foo',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('date_created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('date_modified', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
        ),
```

Anyone have an idea what to do here? Should one avoid using the Django-supplied User object and just create your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first problem with your model I found is, there is a `comma` in your `OneToOne` field. Remove that.
Then, from the official doc, they are using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` as the reference. So, try the following snippet and do `makemigrations` and `migrate` the Db.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Foo(models.Model):
    """This class represents the Foo model."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='foos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: It was the comma! That's so frustrating, I'd think it would display an error when generating. Importing the User model directly is an option from the official docs too. Thanks for the keen eye!

Comment: Welcome dude ;)